# MimeKit Character Encoding/Decoding Issue

Tags: c#, email, character-encoding, mimekit

While using `MimeKit` to convert `.eml` files to `.msg` files, I'm running into an issue that appears to be related to encoding.

With an EML file containing the following, for instance:

```
--__NEXTPART_20160610_5EF5CF91_471687D
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-2022-jp
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

添付ファイル名テスト
```

The result is garbage in the body content:

```
・Y・t・t・@・C・・・ｼ・e・X・g
```

Additionally, base-64 encoded `ü` characters are showing up as `??` when the EML file is read. I've downloaded the latest release of MimeKit, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

The .eml files open properly with Outlook 2016, but using MimeKit does not appear to be able to read and decode the files properly.

Comment: The edit is very... nitpicky?

I don't mind, but if we're going to nitpick can we at least make the nitpicking consistent?

In other words, MimeKit was edited to `MimeKit` once, but another instance was left in the original font.

Also, .eml was nitpicked to `.eml` in one instance, but not in the subsequent instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your above MIME snippet :(

`Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit` is obviously not true, altho that's not likely to be the problem (MimeKit ignores values of `7bit` and `8bit` for this very reason).

Most importantly, however, is the fact that the charset parameter is `iso-2022-jp` but the content itself is very clearly not `iso-2022-jp` (it looks like `utf-8`).

When you get the `TextPart.Text` value, MimeKit gets that string by converting the raw stream content using the charset specified in the `Content-Type` header. If that is wrong, then the `Text` property will also have the wrong value.

The good news is that `TextPart` has [GetText](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MimeKit_TextPart_GetText.htm) methods that allow you to specify a charset override.

I would recommend trying:

```
var text = part.GetText (Encoding.UTF8);
```

See if that works.

FWIW, `iso-2022-jp` is an encoding that forces Japanese characters into a 7bit ascii form that looks like complete jibberish. This is what your Japanese text would look like if it was actually in `iso-2022-jp`:

```
BE:IU%U%!%$%kL>%F%9%H
```

That's how I know it's not `iso-2022-jp` :)

**Update:**

Ultimately, the solution will probably be something like this:

```
var encodings = new List<Encoding> ();
string text = null;

try {
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding (part.ContentType.Charset,
        new EncoderExceptionFallback (),
        new DecoderExceptionFallback ());
    encodings.Add (encoding);
} catch (ArgumentException) {
} catch (NotSupportedException) {
}

// add utf-8 as our first fallback
encodings.Add (Encoding.GetEncoding (65001, 
    new EncoderExceptionFallback (),
    new DecoderExceptionFallback ()));

// add iso-8859-1 as our final fallback
encodings.Add (Encoding.GetEncoding (28591, 
    new EncoderExceptionFallback (),
    new DecoderExceptionFallback ()));

for (int i = 0; i < encodings.Count; i++) {
    try {
        text = part.GetText (encodings[i]);
        break;
    } catch (DecoderFallbackException) {
        // this means that the content did not convert cleanly
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The .eml file was created by a third party program, so I'll follow up with them; sounds like an issue with their app.

Comment: FWIW, I just updated my answer with a possible generic solution to your problem.